# Unable to remove network printers, they keep reappearing

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-printer

I am having problems deleting printers on a Windows Server 2012 they keep reappearing after a while when the PrintSpooler service is running.

I have tried to list the printers in powershell with the following command but the don't even appear on that list.

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer
```

I have a suspicion that they were added via Remote Desktop connection's printer redirection, which I have now disabled.

Also in the Printer Properties window, Hardware tab, the Location is something like

```
\Users\S-1-5-18\Printers\^\^\printserver^\printername
```

I have tried to delete all traces of those printers from all registry locations I could find them in, but the keep coming back..

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Turn off the print spooler?

Comment: Yes, but as soon as I turn it back on they come back...

Comment: So... leave it off?

Comment: And how is printing going to work?

Comment: From your print server, hopefully.  Of course, if this *is* your print server, that seems like a detail worth mentioning, among others... such as how your printers are deployed, relevant GPOs and scripts, for starters.

Comment: I am not fully familiar with the deployment of printers on the print servers, this is an application server that adds network printers programatically, which we now want to disable and just add them manually. However if I disable the Print Spooler service (C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe) on this server it is not possible to add printers and all existing ones are unavailable. So does this qualify this server a "Print Server" as well?

Comment: No, what you have described is not a print server.  What you need to do is determine precisely how the printers are being added programmatically, and stop it.  It could be GPO, GPP, script, deployment through the printer object, or even an application that's doing this, so it's not possible to say exactly how, without more information.  Anyway, once you've figured it out and stopped the programmatic deployment, you can delete the printers that have been created (without them coming back), and add the ones you want.

Comment: Why do you need to delete the printers?  If they are added by remote desktop then it is the ones you can access from your profile on the local machine, remove them from there if they are no longer required.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the print spooler before deleting the printer?